# Use abstract method after inheriting

Tags: python, inheritance, intellij-idea, pycharm, multiple-inheritance

Using PyCharm IDE.
I want to inherit 2 abstract classes A+B into 1 new class C. I want to implement one of the class' methods and use the other class' methods, which is implemented in a later class E usind A's implementation in D.

My problem is: When creating class C, intelliJ wants me to implement all methods, so class A's methods and class B's methods. I just want to implement class A methods but need class B's "interface" to know which methods are available to me. Is there a way to tell intelliJ that I don't want to implement a certain classes abstractmethods in a new class?

Or even - Is there a way to do all of this in a nicer fashion?

```
class A(metaclass=ABCMeta):
    """interface class"""  
    @abstractmethod
    def click(self, c): pass

class B(metaclass=ABCMeta):
    """interface class"""   
    @abstractmethod
    def do_something(self): pass

class C(A, B):
    # implement methods of B here, use abstract methods of A 
    # as interface to know what methods are available for use
    def do_something(self):
        self.click("anything")

class D(A):
    # implement A
    def click(self, c):
        print("I clicked {}".format(c))

class E(C,D):
    # merge implementations to create runnable `do_something()`
    def main():
        self.do_something()

E.main()
```

Comment: You could simply suppress the inspection: `# noinspection PyAbstractClass`

Answer (score 0):

As written, your class `C` is still abstract since it doesn't implement abstractmethods from `A` - so it should be marked as such:

```
class C(A, B, metaclass=ABCMeta):
    # implement methods of B here, use abstract methods of A 
    # as interface to know what methods are available for use
    def do_something(self):
        self.click("anything")
```

Comment: I've consindered that, but is there a way to still force all abstractmethods of B to be implemented in C when C is declared as ABCMeta?

Comment: No (not directly at least) - but why would you need this when you have the hand on the code ? Anyway: are you sure multiple inheritance is the right solution here ? Perhaps composition+delegation would make more sense ?

Comment: I want to give the code to others to contribute and need them to have the interface of A but implement all of B's methods. Also yes, I'll reconsider the solution with multiple inheritance and try an alternative approach. Thanks for your input